# FolderBrowserDialog does not map network drive letters

Tags: .net, winforms, network-drive, folderbrowserdialog

I am using [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) to choose a folder from a remote host, but it does not show drive letters (e.g. C$,D$), even though all of them are accessible, if I specify the `SelectedPath` property like this: `folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = @"\\" + HostAddress + @"\c$"`, then it can display C$ and other shared folders (UNC Path), but there is also D drive and others on the host host which do not display. I except that every drive letter can be shown.

Comment: Are you after a method that allows you to select unc paths through the browser?

Answer (score 1):

*DriveLetter$* shares are [hidden](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954422) so they have to be explicitly accessed as you've found out.

> ...special **hidden** administrative shares that administrators, programs, and services can use to manage the computer environment or network. These special shared resources are not visible in Windows Explorer or in My Computer.

A couple of work arounds would be

- Map *$DriveLetter* shares as [Network Drives](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive#1TC=windows-7).  Instead of \\<Host>\C$ you access through Z:\
- [Add Non Hidden Shares for each drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-share-the-root-of-a-drive)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with this. From what i could find the only way to get around this is using [Ookii Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/). It implements the Vista Dialog for WPF/winforms which had an address bar.

The address bar ofcourse accepts UNC paths.